# How can I customize the LaTeX export of org babel #+RESULTS?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel

I regularly use org-mode and org-babel to create e.g. exercises or proof-of-principle documents which I export to PDF via the LaTeX exporter. I noticed that the `#RESULTS` generated by a `#+begin_src`-`#+end_src` block are put in a `#+begin_example`-`#+end_example` block, which is exported to LaTeX's `verbatim` environment.

I would like to customize this LaTeX export. I could try and add some `#+LATEX_HEADER` lines customizing the `verbatim` environment (e.g. using the `fancyvrb` package), however, ideally I would like to use the `listings` environment for the output. Is this possible?

EDIT: 
I currently use the `listings` package to format the `src` blocks, so ideally I would like to use the same formatting for both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be a "smarter" way but if you don't use `EXAMPLE` blocks for other purpose you could instruct the latex exporter to export them as `lstlisting` environment, using [export filters](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html#Advanced-configuration).

```el
(defun my-latex-export-example-blocks (text backend info)
  "Export example blocks as listings env."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert text)
      ;; replace verbatim env by listings
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (replace-string "\\begin{verbatim}" "\\begin{lstlisting}")
      (replace-string "\\end{verbatim}" "\\end{lstlisting}")
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-example-block-functions
         'my-latex-export-example-blocks)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For my current use case, this is indeed enough. I simply embed your code example in an `emacs-lisp` `SRC` block so that it only applies to this Org file. Note that the environment provided by the `listings` package is actually called `lstlisting`. With this example I can even specify options (e.g. `\\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]`) specifically for the output/examples. Thanks for the great MWE on export filters. I had tried to write one myself some time ago, but failed.

Answer (score 6):

For reference I found [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-09/msg01094.html) message on the org-mode mailing list which mentions a way to do this by means of file local `#+LATEX_HEADER` lines which use the `fancyvrb` package and redefine the verbatim environment that org-mode `#+RESULTS` blocks get exported to via:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small,formatcom = {\color[rgb]{0.5,0,0}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this @phaebz. I guess I found the same mailing list post at some point. I have been using it for quite some time now.