# org mode — verbatim syntax for new type of block

Tags: org-export, latex

the following MWE shows how I have created a new type of environment called a `codebox` to store output in, so that I can format it inside a box with LaTeX.  However, I don't know how to make Org Mode treat each `#+begin_codebox ... #+end_codebox` environment so that its contents are preserved verbatim.

**This works:**

[image]

*Source:*

```
#+TITLE: MWE
#+LATEX_HEADER: \RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\scriptsize}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{mdframed}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{example}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\scriptsize]}{\end{BVerbatim}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{codebox}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{mdframed}\begin{example}}{\end{example}\end{mdframed}}

#+begin_src R :session :results output org :wrap codebox
# Sample from the vector 'a' 1 element.
a<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
sample(a, 3)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_codebox
[1] "b" "e" "d"
#+end_codebox
```

However, if I make a codebox that includes things like `~` or `_`, etc., those symbols are given a special interpretation by the org mode exporter.

**This isn't what I want:**

[image]

*Source (to add to file above):*

```
* Not so great

#+begin_codebox
This ~ is a test_of_the{codebox}
#+end_codebox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution, but it does seem excessively clever!

**Based on this:** https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19941/8406

**Key idea:** wrap with `example` rather than `codebox`, then use built-in ability to alter the formatting of example blocks.

Installing some adapted elisp code from the linked answer:

```lisp
(defun my-latex-export-example-blocks (text backend info)
  "Export example blocks as custom results env."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert text)
      ;; replace verbatim env by 'results'
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\\\\\(begin\\|end\\){verbatim}" nil t)
        (replace-match "\\\\\\1{results}"))
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-example-block-functions
             'my-latex-export-example-blocks)
```

Updated MWE:

```
#+TITLE: MWE
#+LATEX_HEADER: \RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\scriptsize}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{mdframed}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{contents}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{BVerbatim}[fontsize=\scriptsize]}{\end{BVerbatim}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{results}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{mdframed}\begin{contents}}{\end{contents}\end{mdframed}}

* Example

#+begin_src R :session :results output org :wrap example
# Sample from the vector 'a' 1 element.
a<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
sample(a, 3)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
[1] "c" "f" "e"
#+end_example

* This works now

#+begin_example
This ~ is a test_of_the{codebox}
#+end_example
```